# "Valid signing identity not found" Error

Tags: xcode, identity, signing, provisioning-profile

Every time I try to build my application for archiving I get this error "No unexpired provisioning profiles found that contain any of the keychain's signing certificates"
So I go into Organizer-Devices and I select provisioning profiles and notice that there is a warning on the profiles

I would add a pic, if I had enough points...

I  worked on this error for the entire day, and I have not gotten any further

If you know how to fix this please respond

Thanks